# content not breaking property (nobr) in TCPDF is not working properly in second number of <td> tag

Tags: php, tcpdf

My Problem is that i have added nobr property to price section so if content of price section is more than page one then it automatic break to second page. Then i have used that same nobr propery for the Upholstery section which is another td tag but this content is always start from second page but it show in first page because size of content of Upholstery section is enough to place in page 1.

check this is my PDf code.

```
<table style="font-family:spectrummt;color:rgb(84,42,17);font-size:10">
<tr >
  <td style="width:960px;" >
     <div>
        <h3><span style="font-size:12">Description</span></h3>
        <span style="font-size:8.8">This website Description</span> 
     </div>
     <div>
        <h3><span style="font-size:12">Details</span></h3>
        <span style="font-size:8.8">Part of The Lily Collection, a collaboration with Mark D Sikes, this<br /> dining chair combines a geometric cane base with curvaceous back<br /> and arms wrapped in rattan, with a diamond lattice rattan design on<br /> the chair back and sides. The Lily Collection is handmade by skilled<br /> weavers in Soane Britain’s Leicestershire rattan workshop. The chair is<br /> completed with loose cushions and ties upholstered in a Soane Britain<br /> or client’s own fabric.<br /> Available in Soane’s standard rattan finishes. With loose seat and back<br /> cushion and traditional ties, and a padded deck.</span> 
     </div>
     <div nobr="true">
        <h3><span style="font-size:12">Price</span></h3>
        <span style="font-size:8.8">All prices quoted are ex works.<br /> All prices quoted are ex works.<br /> All prices quoted are ex works.<br /> All prices quoted are ex works.<br /> All prices quoted are ex works.<br /> All prices quoted are ex works.<br /> All prices quoted are ex works.<br /> All prices quoted are ex works.<br /> All prices quoted are ex works.<br /> All prices quoted are ex works.<br /> <br /> </span> 
     </div>
     <div>
        <h3><span style="font-size:12">Lead Time</span></h3>
        <span style="font-size:8.8">(from receipt of deposit): 12 weeks</span> 
     </div>
     <div>
        <h3><span style="font-size:12">Delivery</span></h3>
        <span style="font-size:8.8">Carriage charges can be quoted upon confirmation of the delivery<br /> address.</span> 
     </div>
  </td>
  <td style="width:115px"></td>
  <td style="width:1030px;" >
     <div>
        <h3><span style="font-size:12">Dimensions</span></h3>
        <span style="line-height:1200">870mm height x 690mm depth x 560mm width<br /> Height to Seat with cushion: 485mm<br /> Height to Arm: 640mm<br /> 34.25” height x 27” depth x 22” width<br /> Height to Seat with cushion: 19”<br /> Height to Arm: 25”<br /> Please allow a 20mm tolerance for all rattan pieces, as these made of a<br /> hand-woven natural product.<br /> All upholstery is dacron-wrapped foam. Alternate fills are available<br /> with an upcharge upon request.</span> 
     </div>
     <div nobr="true">
        <h3><span style="font-size:12">Upholstery</span></h3>
        <span style="font-size:8.8">This is upolstery<br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> </span> 
     </div>
  </td>
```

Below is output image
[image]

Comment: This seems to be an almost exact duplicate of your previous question, [Page not breaking using nobr property is not working for second number of td tag of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615848/page-not-breaking-using-nobr-property-is-not-working-for-second-number-of-td-tag) Please do not create such duplicates; you recently edited your previous question, now you have to have some patience for people to react to it.

Comment: yes you are right but no one can give answer of my question i have already waited for one day so i think i can add second time so some new user can check my latest question.

Comment: Imagine if everyone did that, as soon as they think they don’t get the “priority support” they think they deserve ... this place would be flooded in no time. A mere day of waiting does not justify a duplicate IMHO.

Comment: Anyway you are right I have keep in mind this thing.